# Parametric equation of the ellipse: clockwise or counterclockwise rotation when varying the parameter

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

Given an ellipse of semi-axes $a$ and $b$ centered on the point $(x_0,y_0)$,

$$\frac{(x-x_0)^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{(y-y_0)^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$$

It can be expressed using parametric coordinates:

$$\vec{F}(t)=(x(t), y(t))$$

$$x(t)=a \cos (t)+x_0 $$
$$ y(t)=b \sin (t)+y_0$$

Then, if $P(x(t),y(t))$ is a point belonging to the ellipse, how can we know whether it will move clockwise or counterclockwise when the parameter $t$ is varied?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $t=0$ and $t=90^\circ$

Comment: It will depend on the signs of $a$ and $b$: both positive or both negative, counterclockwise; opposite signs, clockwise. To see that without calculus, just plug in some values of $t$ like $0, 90, 180, 270$ (in degrees of course ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a,b>0$, the movement will be counterclockwise. Note that $F'(0)=(0,b)$, which points upwards. So, since $F(0)$ is the point of the ellipse located more to the right, it starts moving counterclockwise. Since $F'(t)$ is never $0$, the movement cannot become clockwise after.